# How to install pygame windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I just tried to install pygame for python 3.4 my windows computer, but apparently I need to extract the whl file? I have seen other questions like this one on stackoverflow and it says to write in commant prompt:

```
pip install package-name.whl
```

However, when I tried this, I got in return:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal of external command, operable program, or batch file.
```

Is this because I have Windows 10? Please help!

Comment: See: [How to install pip on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).

Comment: nope works fine on windows 10 just make sure you put the whl file in the scripts folder with pip or give the path to it

Comment: you need to add pip to the path variable to run it from default cmd. Just navigate to the python scripts folder and run it from there

Answer (score 2):

For me this command works.->**py -m pip install -U pygame --user**
But first, make sure you properly configure your environment variables.
This tutorial **http://www.aaronstannard.com/how-to-setup-a-proper-python-environment-on-windows/** will help you how to setup environment variables for python, make sure you do it correctly only step 2 ,no need to do any other steps from this tutorial, now you can follow my steps that were listed below. I will assume that you have already installed python in your computer

> Step1

Search for cmd and Right click on cmd and do run as administrator.

> Step2

Run the command, **py -m pip install -U pygame --user**, but before you run this command first of all make sure you configure your environment variables properly.

> Step3

Type **python** in command prompt, this will take you to the python command line which will look like this ">>>".If not then you have a problem with your system variables.

> Step4

Make sure you are in python command line and then type **import pygame**,and after this press **ctrl+z and enter** that will take you out from python command line.

> Step5

Make sure you are not in python command line and then run this command **py -m pygame.examples.aliens**,if the game starts then congrats you are done.

Answer (score 1):

It can be possible that the pip/ wheel is not installed 
follow this link to install pip [link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html)

If already installed maked sure it is updated if not

You can use this code to update: `python –m ensurepip –-upgrade` or `pip install --upgrade pip`

To install wheel `pip install wheel` or upgrade `pip install wheel --upgrade`

once this is done you are good to install pygame

At the command line, make sure you’re in the same directory as the .whl file and run
`pip install package-name.whl`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your pip isn't working correctly. To make sure it works, go to this folder C:\Python34\Scripts in windows explorer, hold shift and then right click. press 'open command prompt' here and then try to run pip.

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when the command entered, pip in this case, isn't found.

I just got pygame working on Windows 10 with these steps.

Download pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl from [UCI](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

Run the `cmd` shell and enter

```
> cd C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts
> pip install C:\Users\<me>\Downloads\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl
```

Start the Python 3.5 console.  Therein enter

```
import pygame
dir(pygame)
```

No errors from either  means that Pygame is ready for your command.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pygame
```

that's all you need, just remember to use it correctly in your code

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have pip installed. You can run:

```
pip install pygame
```

in command prompt or a simulated terminal.

If you don't have pip already installed, please refer to this: (hope I helped!)

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-pip-for-python/

Answer (score 0):

I updated my pip, then ran the command prompt (cmd) as adminstrator, then I issued a python command:

`-m pip install pygame`

And it installed pygame.